# Java Properties file help

Tags: java

Здравствуйте Уважаемые. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Properties file изменить значение по ключу. У меня при изменении одного ключа, меняется весь файл, и остается единственная запись(через `setProperty`). Заранее спасибо.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("First.properties");
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("First.properties");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(in);
in.close();
props.setProperty("country", "america");
props.store(out, null);
out.close();
```

`setProperty` работает таким образом, что оставляет одну запись в файле `country=america`(при этом удаляет все остальные), а я хотел бы оставить все записи которые были в файле, изменив при этом только одну строчку. Все примеры которые я видел, делали это через `setProperty`, что приводило не к изменение конкретного значения,а к перезаписи файла.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setProperty работает не так как Вы написали, а меняет только один параметр, не трогая и тем более не удаляя остальные. Всё дело в том, что открытие файла через FileOutputStream стирает его содержимое. Правильный путь - открыть файл для чтения, считать параметры, закрыть, изменить параметры, открыть файл для записи и записать параметры. Приведённый ниже код решает Вашу задачу:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("First.properties");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(in);
in.close();

props.setProperty("country", "america");

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("First.properties");
props.store(out, null);
out.close();
```

Comment: Спасибо, добрый ты человек) и правда-мой косяк(а я извратился, сделал перебором строк и перезаписью в другой файл)